# Xcode project build failed

Tags: ios, xcode, cocoapods

Trying to build my project and Xcode 9.2 shows compile error:

```
ld: warning: directory not found for option '-F/Users/user/playgrounds/ios/app/build/Release-iphoneos/Alamofire'
ld: framework not found FBAudienceNetwork
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

Podfile is:

```
source 'https://github.com/CocoaPods/Specs.git'
platform :ios, '8.2'
project 'app.xcodeproj'
target "app" do
    use_frameworks!
    pod 'GoogleMaps'
    pod 'Charts'
    pod "OAStackView"
    pod 'Alamofire', '~> 4.4'
    pod 'SwiftyJSON', '~> 3.1'
    pod 'Appodeal', '1.3.9'
    pod 'Firebase/Core'
    pod 'Firebase/Messaging'
end
```

Tried to remove remove Podfile.lock and `pod update` but it did not helped.
Adding FBAudienceNetwork to Podfile provides this issue:

> [!] The 'Pods-app' target has frameworks with conflicting names: fbaudiencenetwork.framework.

How this problem can be solved?

Comment: maybe you have the same framework linked in build settings of your project?

Comment: can you hit cmd `pod deintegrate`  & again `pod install` check if that works for you.

Comment: Sorry, I updated Appodeal pod to 2.x.x and it solved problem, so I can't check your solution

Answer (score 1):

Updating Appodeal to 2.x.x solved problem.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

Product/Edit schemes/Manage schemes, select PODS.

Comment: Thanks for advice, but I updated Appodeal pod to 2.x.x and it solved problem, so I can't check your solution